# Sending GET Request with a JSON body

Tags: php, laravel, guzzle

I am trying to consume an API that allows JSON bodies to be sent to a GET endpoint, however I cannot find a way to send a body to a GET endpoint.

I have tried:

```
Http::withBody(json_encode([
     'field' => 'value',
]), 'application/json')
->get('foo.bar/auth/user');
```

Which sends no body.

And:

```
Http::asJson()
->get('foo.bar/auth/user', [
     'field' => 'value',
]);
```

Which turns the body into query params.

How can I achieve this?

Note: Its not under my control whether the API is correct by allowing JSON bodies with a GET endpoint.

Comment: The HTTP client may itself not support GET bodies, since it's very uncommon and arguably non-standard.  You might have to use something more manual to send the request, like CURL.

Comment: you could attempt to use the `send` method instead: `send(string $method, string $url, array $options = [])` ... in the `$options` array you can define the body ... look into the `Illuminate\Http\Client\PendingRequest` class to see what it offers

Comment: @lagbox Send worked, could you put it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the `send` method, which is what `get` ends up calling to send the request:

```
Http::asJson()->send($method, $url, ['json' => $data]);
```